# How do you convert rgb to uint index_or_rgb

Tags: qt

I am using

```
QImage::setPixel(x, y, uint index_or_rgb); // http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setPixel-2
```

But I don't know how to convert rgb values into a uint. How do you convert rgb values into uint?

```
QColor *c = new QColor(185, 20, 120);
image.setPixel(i, i2, c->value()); // this doesnt work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1.` See the documentation of `QImage::setPixel`:

> If the image's format is either monochrome or 8-bit, the given index_or_rgb value must be an index in the image's color table, otherwise the parameter must be a QRgb value.

I assume your image is neither monochrome nor 8-bit, so you need to obtain `QRgb` value (which is a typedef of `unsigned int`).

`2.` Next, if you look at `QColor` documentation, you can notice that `QRgb` value from a `QColor` should be obtained using `rgb()` (or `rgba()` if you use alpha channel in your image).

`3.` Note that `QColor` should not be created using `new`. It's usually created on stack and passed by value. So your code should be corrected as the following:

```
QColor c(185, 20, 120);
image.setPixel(i, i2, c.rgba());
```

Also note that `value()` doesn't return a representation of entire `QColor`. It just returns one of 3 components of HSV representation of `QColor`. It seems that `value()` is completely unrelated to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

This way maybe works, just try it out.

```
setPixel(x, y, qRgb(185, 20, 120));
```